# Accessing Authenticated User Information with Azure Mobile Service .Net backend for Android Client

Tags: android, .net, oauth, social-networking, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to explore Microsoft Azure Mobile services for Android client. I am able to create the mobile service and database on Azure, also able to access the same from my Android client using [these tutorials](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/). Currently I am struggling with Authenticating user from the social site likes Google/Facebook/Twitter/Microsoft and get their personal info with the help of latest updates added to the Azure Mobile Services .NET backend [given here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/02/custom-login-scopes-single-sign-on-new-asp-net-web-api-updates-to-the-azure-mobile-services-net-backend/).

My question is how to access these updates in Android client. Or any other way by which I can able to access all the persoal information related to an authenticated user using .net backend for Android client. Please help me here...